# assembly x86 (ia-32): how to use struct stat

Tags: assembly, system-calls, x86

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
    mov eax,5 ;open
    mov ebx,filename ;path to file
    mov ecx,0000o ;O_RDONLY
    int 0x80
    mov ebx,eax ;fd
    mov eax,0x1c; fstat
    mov ecx,structvar ;address of struct
    int 0x80
    ;**HERE**
    mov eax,0x1 ;exit
    mov ebx,0x5 ;ret code
    int 0x80

section .data
    filename: db "/home/USER/file.txt"

section .bss
    structvar: resb 88 ;struct stat is 88 bytes in x86
```

i'm trying to use the `fstat` syscall but i have a problem where you see `;**HERE**` in the code. In fact the value of `$eax` after the syscall is a negative number (the last time i run this code was -75).
This mean that i am doing something wrong but i cannot understand what. Any hint??

PS: i'm running Gentoo x86

Thanks

**EDIT: code update**

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
    mov eax,5 ;open
    mov ebx,filename ;path to file
    mov ecx,0000o ;O_RDONLY
    int 0x80
    mov ebx,eax ;fd
    mov eax,0x6c ;newfstat
    mov ecx,structvar ;address struct
    int 0x80
    mov eax,0x1 ;exit
    mov ebx,0x5 ;ret code
    int 0x80

section .data
    filename: db "/home/USER/file.txt",0x0

section .bss
    structvar: resb 88 ;struct stat in x86 is 88 bytes
```

Comment: -75 is -EOVERFLOW: perhaps the file is very large?

Comment: the file is 1812 bytes so it isn't an overflow... :(

Comment: i also tried with a file which size is 2 bytes but nothing changed, always `-75`. Also if i do `x/40cb &structvar` it is filled with only `0` ;-/

Answer (score 2):

You are using the old fstat system call which indeed has some limitations and is obsolete. You can probably see the message in syslog:

> vmunix: VFS: Warning: a.out using old stat() call. Recompile your
>   binary.

You should use the syscall newfstat (0x6c) or fstat64 (0xc5), or better yet, avoid files, i/o and syscalls in asm if possible.

Also note you have forgotten to zero terminate your string. If it happens to be zero terminated it's only because it's accidentally followed by a 0.

Comment: thanks a lot! Now the retcode is `0` and the variable `structvar` is filled with some value (but they aren't correct and i don't know why xD)

Comment: Run your program through `strace -v`. I am pretty sure the returned values are fine and you are just using wrong struct layout.

Comment: yes, `open` syscall is correct, `fstat` is using the correct `fd` but the value are all strange like `st_size=250495198606543074` (and the size should be `1812`...). You saying that i am using a wrong struct layout but what do you mean exactly? PS i updated the code in the answer

Comment: ps the output of `strace -v` : `fstat(3, {st_dev=makedev(1048584, 3775922179), st_ino=98724, st_mode=S_IFIFO, st_nlink=7782480740352, st_uid=8, st_gid=1390561506, st_blksize=0, st_blocks=0, st_size=250495198606543074, st_atime=0, st_mtime=0, st_ctime=0}) = 0`

Comment: i made a c program to check the above (and correct) value which are: `fstat(3, {st_dev=makedev(8, 3), st_ino=1052177, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=1812, st_atime=2014/01/24-12:05:06, st_mtime=2014/01/24-12:05:06, st_ctime=2014/01/24-12:05:06}) = 0`